# Onfido SDK one document type straight to capture screen?

Tags: javascript, sdk

According to the Onfido web ui SDK readme supplying one doctype should take you straight to the capture screen.

". If documentTypes only includes one document type, users will not see the document selection screen and instead will be taken to the capture screen directly."

https://github.com/onfido/onfido-sdk-ui

However it takes me to the document selection screen with one document.

Here is the relevant part of my init options object.

```
Integration configuration:
containerId: 'onfido-mount',
steps: [
'document'

],
documentTypes: {passport: true},
useLiveDocumentCapture: true,
uploadFallback: true,
onComplete: function(data) {`
```

I've opened an issue but was wondering if anyone else had any ideas in the meantime?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `documentTypes` configuration to the `document` step options like in the example below

```
Onfido.init({
    containerId: 'onfido-mount',
    steps: [{ 
        type: 'document',
        options: {
            documentTypes: { 
                passport: true
            },
            useLiveDocumentCapture: true,
            uploadFallback: true
        }
    }]
})
```

The `documentTypes` configuration only applies to the `document` step, therefore you need to pass it to the document step options.